# Error With String as Sequelize/Postgres Foreign Key

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm building a relationship between electrical stations and readings from their meters. There seems to be an error that Postgres/Sequelize expects the foreign key to be of type `INTEGER`. I'd love to fix it.

### Models

```
  var Station = sequelize.define('Station', {
    id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
      }, 
    kin: DataTypes.STRING,
    // other columns

  var EKMreading = sequelize.define('EKMreading', {
    id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
      }, 
    "Meter": DataTypes.STRING,
    // other columns
```

### Associations

```
EKMreading.belongsTo( Station, { as: 'KIN', foreignKey: 'kin'});
Station.hasMany( EKMreading, { as: { singular: 'reading', plural: 'readings'} } );
```

### Broken Code

```
EKMreading.create({ data blah, blah })
    .then(function( reading ) {
        Station.find({where: {ekmOmnimeterSerial: reading.Meter}})
            .then(function( station ) {
                reading.setKIN( station.kin ); // breaks stuff, see below
                station.addReading( reading )
                  .then(function() {
                    console.log('Made relationship.');
                  });
             });
          });
```

### Error (Abridged)

```
Error setting reading on Station. { [SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: "007-0020-001-04-K"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Always the Simple Stuff

Based on the error, I thought that there was an issue with the me giving a primary key which was a string, but it wanted an integer.

The true issue is that you have to pass the entire instance to the setter:

```
// before
reading.setKIN( station.kin ); 

// after
reading.setKIN( station );
```

The setter will automatically take the primary key from the station and assign it as the foreign key in the reading.

### Still Unknown

How do you set the foreign key to be different than the primary key of another table? For example, how could I make the foreign key on the reading correspond to the Station's KIN instead of its autoincrementing ID?

Comment: In sequelize, foreign keys can only point to primary keys

On the latest version on sequelize you should be able to pass only the key instead of an instance

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using postgres 9.3 instead of 9.4; I wonder if this kills the newer sequelize functionality you're talking about?